# Camera movement in OpenGL raymarched scene

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glm-math

I'm working on a project with OpenGL that uses raymarched graphics and I've run into some trouble controlling the camera.

The scene is generated entirely inside the vertex shader, which is rendered on a 4-vertex plane situated in front of the viewport.  My input function gets key-presses and and mouse movement from the user and calculates the translation and rotation of the camera which gets passed into the fragment shader.

The problem is that the rotation and movement of the camera behaves very strangely.  Not only does simultaneous pitch and yaw cause the camera to roll (even though I'm using quaternions to calculate rotation), but the camera movement (WASD) seems to only move along the world's X and Z axes rather than the camera's relative axes.

Any help with fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glfw/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include "readshader.h"
#include "input.h"

#define GLM_SWIZZLE_XYZ
#define WIDTH 640
#define HEIGHT 480

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

int main() {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    //Vertex array for screen plane
    float vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    unsigned int vbo;
    unsigned int vao;
    unsigned int vs;
    unsigned int fs;
    unsigned int shader_prog;

    //Game logic variables
    vec3 camera_pos = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    quat camera_rot = quat(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    vec2 screen_size = vec2(float(WIDTH), float(HEIGHT));
    float delta_time = 0.0;
    float last_time = 0.0;

    unsigned int a_camera_pos;
    unsigned int a_camera_rot;
    unsigned int a_screen_size;
    unsigned int a_delta_time;

    //Read shader code from GLSL files
    string vs_str = readShader("vert_pass.glsl");
    string fs_str = readShader("frag_raymarch_test.glsl");
    const char* vs_source = vs_str.c_str();
    const char* fs_source = fs_str.c_str();

    //Initialize GLFW and create window
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress);
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    //Set GLFW input parameters
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_RAW_MOUSE_MOTION, GLFW_TRUE);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouseCallback);

    //Create VAO and VBO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Compile shaders and create shader program
    vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vs_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fs_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    shader_prog = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader_prog, vs);
    glAttachShader(shader_prog, fs);
    glLinkProgram(shader_prog);

    glDetachShader(shader_prog, vs);
    glDetachShader(shader_prog, fs);
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    glUseProgram(shader_prog);

    //Setup attribute arrays and uniform variables for vertex shader
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    a_camera_pos = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog, "vert_camera_pos");
    a_camera_rot = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog, "vert_camera_rot");
    a_screen_size = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog, "vert_screen_size");
    a_delta_time = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog, "vert_delta_time");

    //Main event loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        //Calculate delta time
        delta_time = glfwGetTime() - last_time;
        last_time = glfwGetTime();

        //Pass game information to shader program
        glProgramUniform3fv(shader_prog, a_camera_pos, 1, value_ptr(camera_pos));
        glProgramUniform4fv(shader_prog, a_camera_rot, 1, value_ptr(camera_rot));
        glProgramUniform2fv(shader_prog, a_screen_size, 1, value_ptr(screen_size));
        glProgramUniform1f(shader_prog, a_delta_time, delta_time);

        //Process user input
        input(window, &camera_pos, &camera_rot, delta_time);

        //Rendering procedure
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    //Cleanup and exit
    glDeleteProgram(shader_prog);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

input.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <glfw/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#define GLM_SWIZZLE_XYZW 
#define SPEED 5.0
#define SENS 0.001

using namespace glm;

float camera_pitch = 0.0;
float camera_yaw = 0.0;

bool first = true;
float lastx = 0.0;
float lasty = 0.0;
float offsetx;
float offsety;

void input(GLFWwindow* window, vec3* camera_pos, quat* camera_rot, float delta_time) {
    float step = SPEED * delta_time;
    vec3 camera_fwd = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    vec3 camera_up = vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    vec3 camera_right = vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    quat quatx;
    quat quaty;

    glfwPollEvents();

    //Build rotation quaternion from camera angles
    quatx = angleAxis(camera_yaw, camera_up);
    quaty = angleAxis(camera_pitch, camera_right);
    *camera_rot = quatx * quaty;

    //Update camera axis positions
    camera_fwd = *camera_rot * camera_fwd * conjugate(*camera_rot);
    camera_right = *camera_rot * camera_right * conjugate(*camera_rot);

    //Check keyboard presses
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W)) {
        *camera_pos -= camera_fwd * step;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S)) {
        *camera_pos += camera_fwd * step;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A)) {
        *camera_pos -= normalize(cross(camera_fwd, camera_up)) * step;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D)) {
        *camera_pos += normalize(cross(camera_fwd, camera_up)) * step;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE)) {
        *camera_pos += camera_up * step;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT_CONTROL)) {
        *camera_pos -= camera_up * step;
    }
}

void mouseCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double posx, double posy) {
    if (first) {
        lastx = -posx;
        lasty = -posy;
        first = false;
    }

    offsetx = -posx - lastx;
    offsety = lasty + posy;
    lastx = -posx;
    lasty = -posy;
    offsetx *= SENS;
    offsety *= SENS;
    camera_yaw += offsetx;
    camera_pitch += offsety;

    if (camera_pitch > 89.0) {
        camera_pitch = 89.0;
    }

    if (camera_pitch < -89.0) {
        camera_pitch = -89.0;
    }
}
```

vertex_pass.glsl:

```
#version 460
//Passes variables from attributes to next shader

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform vec3 vert_camera_pos;
uniform vec4 vert_camera_rot;
uniform vec2 vert_screen_size;
uniform float vert_delta_time;

out vec3 camera_pos;
out vec4 camera_rot;
out vec2 screen_size;
out float delta_time;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
    camera_pos = vert_camera_pos;
    camera_rot = vert_camera_rot;
    screen_size = vert_screen_size;
    delta_time = vert_delta_time;
}
```

frag_raymarch_test.glsl:

```
#version 460

#define MAX_STEPS 100
#define MAX_DIST 10000.0
#define SURF_DIST 0.001
#define NORMAL_SAMPLE_SIZE 0.001
#define TAU 6.283185
#define PI 3.141592

in vec3 camera_pos;
in vec4 camera_rot;
in vec2 screen_size;
in float delta_time;

out vec3 color;

vec3 rotateVector(vec4 quat, vec3 vec) {
    return vec + 2.0 * cross(cross(vec, quat.xyz) + quat.w * vec, quat.xyz);
}

//SDF
float getSD(vec3 p) {
    vec4 s = vec4(0, 1, 6, 1);
    float sphere_dist = length(p - s.xyz) - s.w;
    float plane_dist = p.y;
    float d = min(sphere_dist, plane_dist);

    return d;
}

float getDist(vec3 p) {
    float dist = 0;

    //SDF
    dist = getSD(p);

    return dist;
}

float raymarch(vec3 ro, vec3 rd) {
    float dist = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPS; i++) {
        vec3 p = ro + rd * dist;
        dist += getDist(p);

        if(dist >= MAX_DIST || dist <= SURF_DIST) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return dist;    
}

void main() {
    vec2 uv = (gl_FragCoord.xy - 0.5 * screen_size) / screen_size.y;

    //vec3 ro = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    //vec3 ro = camera_pos;
    vec3 ro = camera_pos;
    vec3 fd = normalize(vec3(uv.x, uv.y, 1.0));
    vec3 rd = rotateVector(camera_rot, fd);

    color = vec3(raymarch(ro, rd) / 6.0);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that `q * v * conjugate(q)` is correct with GLM. It looks like `q*v` already applies the correct math to rotate v by q. This may not be the only problem though -- you should check the order of operations everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I went back to using Euler angles instead of quaternions and using them to compute a forward vector for the camera.  The problem was that, in the fragment shader, I was using the camera_fwd vector for the look at point when I should have been using camera_pos + camera_fwd.